# Stream data in a WYSIWYG editor through API - Next.JS and API through .NET

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, vercel, wysiwyg, quill

I have a form in next.js that a user completes and hit send. On send, I call a API that is written in .NET which sends me streamed data of sentences as there is a lot of data of write so I am looking to implement a WYSIWYG editor where I can show the streamed data as you see on ChatGPT when we ask a question.

Is there an editor which supports that where I have a custom API returning the streamed data. I have looked at Novel.sh but that does not work because it has default content and the API property but no way to pass external API and have initial content come from the API